# When reselecting “From my computer” in the image uploader, the “browse files” input is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader

I noticed a bug in the “Add Image” popup that can be reproduced as follows:

1. Click on the <kbd>Add Image</kbd> button
2. Click on the “From the web” radio button
3. Click on “Add Picture” without adding any URL. I see the error message *“You didn't enter a valid URL”*.
4. Click on the “From my computer” radio button
5. You should see the “Add Image” dialog as shown below

[image: The “browse files” input textbox is missing after reselecting “From my computer”.]

As seen in the above image it is now not possible to add files from my computer anymore. We have to close and open the dialog to do so.

My PC Configuration is as follows:

- **OS Verson**: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.
- **Firefox**: 20.0.1
- **IE**: 10.0.9200.16540
- **Google Chrome**: 26.0.1410.64 m

I do not think it is browser dependent as I was able to reproduce it in Firefox, IE10 and Chrome.

Comment: Also reproduced in Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m; Windows XP

Comment: Also Firefox 20.0.1, Windows XP.

Comment: This is OS independent as well. I can reproduce this on both Firefox and Chrome in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My fail.

Didn't use `insertBefore` correctly - I didn't read jQuery documentation properly.

Fix has been pushed - all is well now in the world.